# listbox example

Tags: c#, textbox, listbox, split

How can I add a values to a listbox from a textbox each time a space is pressed (split textbox value on space)

Comment: what? if i read this correct you want to take the value of a textbox and then add it to a list box?

Comment: I award you the most unreadable question of the week.

Comment: No idea what you're asking.  Can you break it down into steps, and possibly show some code that you've tried so we have a starting place to work from?

Comment: Please frame the exact one you required. Untill and unless you tell what is your requirement no one can help

Comment: I think the question is asking this.  As the user types into a text box when they hit space, the newly typed word is added to the list box.  I can't begin to answer this because i am not even sure if the user is asking about windows forms, or asp.net

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, you'll need a `TextChanged` event handler on the textbox. You can then take the text, use `String.Split()` to separate it into individual items, and add them to your listbox.

Comment: what hes says but don't forget that you'll either need to clear the listbox down each time or just add the last element of the array that split produces. (Not that I don't make that mistake every time or anything...)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the edit and it is really what you mean, let's give it a try. Add a new Listener to the TextBox for `KeyPress`, then try this code:

```
private void YourTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar.Equals(' '))
    {
        String[] items = Regex.Split(YourListBox.Text, @"/\w/");
        YourListBox.Items.Clear();
        foreach (String item in items)
             YourListBox.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

This is very quick and dirty, as it will iterate over the whole text each time you press space, but it should do the trick.